# Аналог _getch() при использовании gcc

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, clion

Суть: раньше использовал Visual Studio 2015, в нем, подключаю библиотеку conio.h пользовался функцией _getch(). Сейчас решил пересесть на продукт от Jetbrains - Clion. Всё бы хорошо, но там компилятор gcc и библиотеку conio.h просто не видит. Соответственно, _getch() мне никак не использовать.

Для чего мне собственно это нужно. Вот функции, где я их использую:

```
void pressEnterForContinue()
{
    rewind(stdin);
    printf(" Нажмите ENTER для продолжения работы программы. \n\n");
    while (getchar() != "\r");
}

char getCharCustom()
{
    char c;
    c = _getch();

    if (c == '\r')
        c = '\n';

    if (c != '\b' && c != NULL)
        printf("%c", c);

    return c;
}
```

То есть хочу по нажатию на клавишу получить символ клавиатуры. getchar() возвращает лишь код символа. Придерживаясь чистого С, не используя С++

Comment: Вам для винды? По моему в <windows.h> есть `kbhit()`.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте использовать библиотеку [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html).

Answer (score 1):

Как функцию `_getch()` , можно использовать `read()`

```
int size;
char c; 

for(;;){
   size = read(fileno(stdin),&c,1);
   if(c == '\n'){
     break;
   }
   if (c != '\b' && c != NULL)
     printf("%c", c);

}
```